# Using GraphQL to Filter a JSON Data in Python

Tags: python, json, docker, graphql, graphene-python

I'm using the official `graphene` package in my python project. I have a huge nested JSON data that comes from a running Docker container inspect command and I want to get some fields from that. I can select all those fields each by each and adding them to a dictionary like this:

```
def ContainerConfigs(configs):
    data = {}
    data['Command'] = configs['Args'][-1]
    data['Hostname'] = configs['Config']['Hostname']
    data['Image'] = configs['Config']['Image']
    data['Distro'] = configs['Config']['Labels']['org.label-schema.name']
    data['WorkDir'] = configs['Config']['WorkingDir']
    data['IPAddress'] = configs['NetworkSettings']['Networks']['bridge']['IPAddress']

    return data
```

But It's a weak solution. I think It can be optimized using GraphQL. There is no server, request, and response. I want to create its `Schema` class and send the parameters (JSON and Query) and let the function execute that query and turns back the result. Something like this:

```
import graphene

# I need to find this part of the code
# class Schema(..):
#     ...
# class Query(...):
#     ...

def ContainerConfigs(configs, query):
    schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
    # I need to find a way to pass the configs (Json data) to the Query class to
    # execute the query_string on the data
    query_string = """
    query {
        Args
        Config {
            Hostname
            Image
            WorkingDir
            Label{
                org.label-schema.name
            }
        }
        NetworkSettings{
            Networks{
                bridge{
                    IPAddress
                }
            }
        }
    }
    """
    result = schema.execute(query_string)
    
    return result
```

Comment: What specific issue are you encountering?  Once you retrieve this data, what will you eventually do with it?

Comment: I'm trying to execute a query on the data and respond back the result.

Comment: The other thing that's not obvious to me here is that the result of the GraphQL query will have the same "shape" as the input data; you'll have to use the same nested-dictionary syntax to access it.  This doesn't seem like an obvious technology fit to me.

Comment: no server? schema is for server ... if you know how it works you can simulate response, it's just json (convert your json to required response shape), maybe some graphene parts can be used ... but you don't know how it works, learn it first

Comment: @DavidMaze So, you mean It's better to select all those fields each by each using the above script? I think there would be a better optimized way to get those arbitrary fields from a JSON data in python. I think GraphQL can be helpful in such a scenario.
I've searched a lot about it but couldn't find any proper results. Most of them were about the GraphQL usage in web frameworks like Django or Flask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good technology match: you'll wind up recreating a lot of the Docker API in GraphQL syntax, and it'll still have the same nested-dictionary layout after you query it.

In principle you can write a GraphQL schema that has the same layout as the [Docker API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/).  The schema is *required*; you can't do a GraphQL query without it, but this basically involves making a copy of the entire Docker API object model in your source code.  The other thing to take note of here is that the response to a GraphQL query has the same "shape" as the query (see for example the [Execution](https://graphql.org/learn/execution/) page on graphql.org).

If you did all of this work, and you ran the GraphQL query you show, you'd get a nested-dictionary response like

```py
result = schema.execute(query_string)
hostname = result.data['Config']['Hostname']
```

which isn't any better than what you already have.  (Again, see examples on the Graphene [Execution](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/execution/execute/) documentation page.)

If you want to extract and encapsulate this data in some sort of object, you can create a class to do it for you.  I might write it like so:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

class ContainerConfigs(namedtuple('ContainerConfigs', ['command', 'hostname', ...])):
  @classmethod
  def from_docker_inspect(cls, configs):
    return cls(
      command=configs['Args'][-1],
      hostname=configs['Config']['Hostname'],
      ...
    )

info = ContainerConfigs.from_docker_inspect(configs)
print(f"container hostname (not generally useful): {info.hostname}")
```

Comment: Thanks, let me explain my issue clearer. Imagine that you have a huge JSON data. You need to return 50 out of 150 fields of that data. What is the best way to get those 50 fields? Do you get them one by one and add them to a dictionary (like this -> `data = configs['something']`) in fifty lines or you do something much better?

Comment: If the _server_ supported a GraphQL endpoint, you could request only those 50 specific fields, but it doesn't make much sense to try to run a GraphQL query (with no resolvers or other behaviors) on a JSON object you already have.  Another approach could be an object facade that took the JSON blob in its `__init__` method, and had other methods to return specific properties out of it.  Or, just write extractor functions without a corresponding class.